# Mac OS X Terminal [Use option as meta key] overrides backslash in spanish keyboard

Tags: mac, keyboard, terminal, bash

I already posted this question in stackoverflow:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4811282/mac-os-x-terminal-use-option-as-meta-key-overrides-backslash-in-spanish-keyboar

but I was informed there that this is the right place to ask it.

I check "Use option as meta key" checkbox in Mac OS X Terminal, because I like to use emacs way of moving between words: M-f & M-b.

But if I do that, I can't get the backslash (Option + º; i.e.: Option + key-at-the-left-of-1-in-spanish-keyboard). If I uncheck it, then I can input the backslash, but I don't have M-f & M-b.

Is there a way to get both? This is driving me nuts!

Comment: Hm, but Alt-Shift-7 *gives* you the backslash without remapping something - am I missing something ??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

And, as I already answered you [on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4811282/mac-os-x-terminal-use-option-as-meta-key-overrides-backslash-in-spanish-keyboar), the solution is to put the following line into your `~/.bash_profile`, which remaps the unicode character "∫" (Unicode: E288AB, which is what is sent to your terminal right now in your desired configuration when you press Option + °) to the backslash character:

```
bind '"\033\xE2\x88\xAB"':'"\\"'
```

Comment: Would you mind marking my Answer as the solution then? Also, you´re still having your question open as a duplicate on stackoverflow:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4811282/mac-os-x-terminal-use-option-as-meta-key-overrides-backslash-in-spanish-keyboar

Answer (score 0):

I have built a solution myself and it doesn't require abandoning **Terminal.app** in favour of iTerm 2.

It is a simple status bar app that runs in the background and rewrites all left <kbd>Alt</kbd> + `$KEY` key events to two key events in rapid succession, <kbd>Esc</kbd>, then `$KEY`; however, it only does this if **Terminal.app** is in focus.

You can find the source for the app [here](https://github.com/habibalamin/Metalt). You'll need Xcode to build it.

Comment: Please don't cross post this answer to multiple questions - [question 1](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/7084/mac-os-x-terminal-use-option-as-meta-key-overrides-backslash-in-spanish-keyboa/321623#321623), [question 2](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/21459/use-only-the-left-option-key-as-meta-key-in-terminal-app/321621#321621) and [question 3](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/156154/use-option-as-meta-key-with-ability-to-type-the-symbol/321586#321586).  Instead, leave a comment and link back to it.

Comment: My bad. I will remove this answer and post a comment instead.

Comment: Nope, it says I require 50 reputation to comment.

Answer (score 0):

Asmus' answer does not seem enough because it fixes backslash on bash. But then there's zsh. And Emacs. And etc.

But since there's no way to map non-function keys in Terminal.app, I'm afraid I can't see another solution: you'd have to go ahead and map all the keys you want in all the programs you need them, which is a drag and is not optimum, because you won't ever have *ƒ* and *^[f* at once.

Or try habibalamin's solution, it seems far simpler *and* it keeps distinct functionality for left alt and right alt. I will vote up after trying it.

I can't comment with my rep on this stack site, sorry.