# Why do certain command key combinations not make it to remote screen sharing server?

Tags: keyboard, remote-desktop, screen-sharing, emacs

Using MacOS 10.10.5 on a recent Macbook Air, I'm trying to use X-windows emacs on a remote Linux server via vnc. I have the Mac command key configured as the emacs 'Meta' key, and it works fine for Meta-F, Meta-B, Meta-X, etc...

However, certain key combinations: Meta-P, Meta-Q (command-{P,Q} on the mac) don't get transmitted correctly, making the experience very frustrating.

Is there a way to change something in this setup to get those keys to work?

Answer (score 1):

I believe your issue was addressed in [this](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/12087/emacs-on-mac-os-x-to-alt-or-command?rq=1) thread. I am not familiar with all key bindings in emacs and their binding on older OSes.