# "Use Option as Meta key" with ability to type the # symbol

Tags: keyboard, terminal

I am using Terminal version 2.5, where I have two requirements:

1. I need to be able to type the <kbd>Meta</kbd> key.
2. I need to be able to type the `#` character, too (<kbd>Option</kbd>+<kbd>3</kbd> for the UK keyboard layout)

How can I satisfy both of these? By default, (2) is satisfied, but (1) is not. I can then turn on "Use Option as Meta key", which satisfies (1), but breaks requirement (2).

How can I have both? (It shouldn't be so hard for me to just be able to *type*.)

*Edit:* what I'm looking for, for example, might be a way to just "Use Option as Meta key" for the left/right Option key, or a way to override the "Use Option as Meta key" for the sole exception of the `#` character.

Comment: idk whether it will fix your specific requirement, but Karabiner is a popular tool for that kind of thing - https://pqrs.org/osx/karabiner/

Comment: Which keyboard do you have as on US ones shift 3 is #

Comment: @Mark UK layout

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[iTerm 2](http://iterm2.com) can be configured to only use one option key as meta:

[image]

Comment: Thanks. I found that iTerm's behavior here is somehow buggy; it stopped treating Option as Meta at some point during a session. In the meantime, I've switched to using a graphical version of Emacs which fixes my problem.

Answer (score 1):

For requirement 2 you can choose to make the keyboard an Australian one. The only difference between UK and Australian i <kbd>alt</kbd><kbd>3</kbd> and <kbd>shift</kbd><kbd>3</kbd>. For UK they give # and £ and vice versa for Australian. This means that for an Australian keyboard # is <kbd>shift</kbd><kbd>3</kbd> as it is for a US or under Windows or Linux.

To change the keyboard layout (under Yosemite)  got System Preferences->Language & region - hit the Keyboard Preferences button and use + to add Austrailian  to the left hand column

Answer (score 1):

I have built a solution myself and it doesn't require abandoning **Terminal.app** in favour of iTerm 2.

It is a simple status bar app that runs in the background and rewrites all left <kbd>Alt</kbd> + `$KEY` key events to two key events in rapid succession, <kbd>Esc</kbd>, then `$KEY`; however, it only does this if **Terminal.app** is in focus.

You can find the source for the app [here](https://github.com/habibalamin/Metalt). You'll need Xcode to build it.

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured out how to do this by code:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30336086/make-shift3-produce-not-%C2%A3-on-osx-by-code

If you have developer tools, you can compile & run that from the commandline.